What is the complexity of quantum error corrections?
According to the current state-of-the-art quantum error correction techniques, how many physical qubits are required to obtain $n$ logical qubits after error correction?

It is not that simple. It depends on the physical layout of the device in use, its physical error rates, the QEC code in use, and much more.. E.g. in Google's latest demo with their Willow chip (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-024-08449-y) - they have created one "logical" (it still manifests pretty high error rates but better than the original fidelities of its consistuent physcial qubits) qubit with 101 physical qubits

This depends on the error correcting code you use. An $[[n, k, d]]$ code is a quantum code where $n$ is the total number of qubits, $k$ is the number of logical qubits and $d$ is the code distance.
State of the art "good" qLDPC codes can achieve $k = \Theta(n)$ and $d = \Theta(n)$ in the asymptotic limit. On the other hand, the surface code is more hardware friendly but is a $[[n, 1, \sqrt{n}]]$ code.
